# how to get "AND" of all the values of a boolean column in a single sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to get "AND" of all the values of a boolean column in a single sql query.

[image]

for above the o/p should be false,

if all were true then o/p: true,

if all/atlease one value false , then o/p: false.

Comment: why would you need this?

Comment: i have to enable / disable a button in my C# ui based on this value.

Comment: Loads of ways to do this, but most easiest I can think of is to simply to sum them and check whether the sum is as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT ActiveStatus From TableName where ActiveStatus = 0)
  SELECT 'False'
ELSE
  SELECT 'True'
AS OutputColumn
```

Answer (score 2):

You can indirectly use `MIN` for AND, and `MAX` for OR.if you take into account that a `BIT` colum is either zero or one:

- `MIN`: only if all the values are 1 (true) the result will be 1 (true), it works like `AND`
- `MAX`: if there is at least a 1 (true) the result will be 1 (true), it works like `OR`

If you try to use `MIN` or `MAX` directly on a `BIT` column, it will fail, so you need to cast it to an integer type, and back to bit, like this:

```
SELECT CAST(MIN(CAST(BitColumn AS TINYINT)) AS BIT) FROM Table -- for AND

SELECT CAST(MAX(CAST(Bitcolumn AS TINYINT)) AS BIT) FROM Table -- for OR
```

It's easy to include this in a more complex query, for example one with `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @status varchar(10)
if exists(select null from [Status] where ActiveStatus = 0)
    set @status = 'false'
else
    set @status = 'true'    


select @status  as [Status]
```